# How to set the processor affinity of a managed thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, affinity

I am looking for a way to set the processor affinity of a thread created in managed code by the [System.Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-5.0) class.  I see that [ProcessThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread?view=net-5.0) has a `ProcessorAffinity` property that I understand can be used to set a thread's affinity, however, I do not see a straightforward way to set the affinity of a `System.Thread`. The property `ManagedThreadId` cannot be used to identify a process thread found in the [Process.Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.threads?view=net-5.0), it seems that the `ProcessThread.Id` is the id of an unmanaged thread (are they the same???).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I would have thought that this would have been easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set affinity of CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834588/) and [How Can I Set Processor Affinity in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/) and [Set thread processor affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328751/) and [How to set process affinity to all processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177649/) and [Is Core Affinity Something that We Can Safely Do in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700915/) and [Why set the ProcessorAffinity for a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234297/)

Comment: Regarding the relationship between the `ProcessThread.Id` and the `Thread.ManagedThreadId`, check out this question: [Getting from ProcessThread to a managed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749541/getting-from-processthread-to-a-managed-thread)